# How to create an interactive setup in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if there was a way to have like an interactive setup in discord.py, for example I mean if you do a certain reaction or sends a specific message then the bot will perform an action. I am using commands btw.
Something like

```
await self.client.wait_for_message_content("content")
# Or
await self.client.wait_for_reaction("<:test:0000000000>")
```

Comment: probably looking for `bot.wait_for()` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `on_{event}` functions? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference